# Twitter hardcode login details

Tags: python, node.js, twitter, oauth

What I am trying to do is as follows:

```
t_username = 'XXXXX';
t_password = 'XXXXX';
app_key = 'XXXXX';
app_secret = 'XXXXX';

function login(uname, pword, key, secret) {
  /* Returns something like: [access_token, token_secret] */
}

toks = login(t_username, t_password, app_key, app_secret);

/* Use the 'toks' to make API calls */
```

I have tried looking at some sample codes but they deal in URL(s) and re-directions etc. but they are relevant for a browser app, I am trying to build something like a CLI app.
I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. At the end of your application homepage (where you get your app_key and app_secret), there is a button to create your access token and token secret. Just click it and your access_token and token_secret are generated. Just copy paste them into your app directly and there you go!

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a [Single-user OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples).
This is perfect for the use in command line applications such as yours.

Comment: just saw that your question was only tagged as python. Either way - the linked [Single-user OAuth examples](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples) cover java-script and python. If you should decide to use python I recommend [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy), since it'll give you a nice API abstraction